# libbpf issue: undefined reference to `xsk_umem__create' etc

Tags: ld

I am trying to build nff-go and it requires libbpf. But I ended up with below error when run test.

```
/tmp/go-build107101737/b063/_x002.o: In function `initXDP':
low.cgo2.c:(.text+0x7a09): undefined reference to `xsk_umem__create'
low.cgo2.c:(.text+0x7a5d): undefined reference to `xsk_socket__create'
low.cgo2.c:(.text+0x7a9e): undefined reference to `bpf_get_link_xdp_id'
/tmp/go-build107101737/b063/_x002.o: In function `removeXDP':
low.cgo2.c:(.text+0x7bb5): undefined reference to `xsk_socket__delete'
low.cgo2.c:(.text+0x7bc2): undefined reference to `xsk_umem__delete'
low.cgo2.c:(.text+0x7bd9): undefined reference to `bpf_get_link_xdp_id'
low.cgo2.c:(.text+0x7c1e): undefined reference to `bpf_set_link_xdp_fd'
/tmp/go-build107101737/b063/_x002.o: In function `sendXDP':
low.cgo2.c:(.text+0x8e22): undefined reference to `xsk_socket(float, double)'
```

I installed libbpf per its github guide by

```
git clone https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf.git
cd src
make
```

Now libbpf is installed in /usr/lib64 and it contains the exporting function:

```
nm -D libbpf.so | grep xsk_umem
0000000000014570 T xsk_umem__create
00000000000153c0 T xsk_umem__delete
0000000000014550 T xsk_umem__fd
```

I checked get it in ldconfig path as

```
# ldconfig -v | grep libbpf
ldconfig: Path `/lib64' given more than once
ldconfig: Can't stat /libx32: No such file or directory 
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once 
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/libx32: No such file or directory
    libbpf.so.0 -> libbpf.so.0.0.5
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a bug in nff-go.

It forgets to add -lbpf in compilation script.

Issue 656 is filed for it.

https://github.com/intel-go/nff-go/issues/656